# Laravel - include file only if screen size > 768px

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-dfp

I have a tricky situation where I need to move my Google Ads around on Mobile. I figured out that the best way to do this is to call them using @include but only if certain screen size conditions are met.

I am thinking that the following would work

```
@if($screensize < 768px)
  @include('partials.my-advert')
@endif
```

So my question is how do I get the screen size into PHP? I can get the screen size via JS using `$(window).width();` but then how do I use this value in the Laravel if statement?

Comment: You can't. If you need to position something base on screen size, I'd use CSS media queries

Comment: I tried that first but Google Ads doesn't recognise the CSS hiding the adverts :(

Comment: what is "laravel if statement"?

Comment: Contrary to conventional wisdom I say this is a good question. I have a complicated design requirement which calls for just this - it's virtually (or totally) impossible to solve with media queries alone, I too need the server to know what the screen size is and generate variant HTML accordingly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't detect the screen size with PHP, but alternatively, you can detect the agents. There is a [package](https://github.com/jenssegers/agent), which detects the agents easily where it lets you detect whether the request is coming from desktop/tablet/mobile.

To install it via composer, you can run the command below.

```
$ composer require jenssegers/agent
```

Then add dd the service provider to providers key within the file `config/app.php`.

```
Jenssegers\Agent\AgentServiceProvider::class
```

Furthermore, add the Agent alias to the aliases key,

```
'Agent' => Jenssegers\Agent\Facades\Agent::class
```

Finally, pass the agent variable from your controller to view.

```
$agent = new Agent();
return view('some.view', compact('agent'));
```

Then within your view, you can check whether the agent belongs to some mobile phone or not.

```
@if($agent->isMobile())
  @include('partials.my-advert')
@endif
```

Comment: I'd like to learn why this answer is getting downvotes since it's providing an alternative solution to op's problem where the other answer is already mentioning about and recommending the responsive design.

Comment: Yes I agree, even though people do not agree with the method I want to use, you have provided a perfectly good answer to my question.

Comment: Will this work on desktop when I resize my browser window? Probably not. Detecting screen size and having Laravel process that isn't impossible, it's a matter of reading the screen size client side and passing it to the backend via AJAX.

Answer (score 9):

There's absolutely no point in trying to do it this way, because this entire approach is antiquated. Sure, you could pass the `$(window).width()` from the client in javascript back to the server in PHP, but then what happens if the user resizes their window?

This is why, today, what is encouraged, instead, is [responsive design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design). Even [Google Adsense has responsive ad units](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689?hl=en) for this.

Responsive design doesn't require the back-end to know anything about the client in order to properly render things on the page. Instead, the client makes no assumptions whatsoever about how content is rendered on the client UA, and allows advanced CSS and JS to deal with the rendering directly and responsively. Meaning, that your content is never different regardless of the screen size.

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is one such front-end framework that makes use of responsive design. There's also the [Material design](https://material.google.com/), which has [many implementations](http://materializecss.com/) that are also responsive.

Comment: Yeah I'm using all of the above just having found this was the only way I could think of to change placement of a google ad based on screensize.

Comment: I think you're confusing rendering of content with content. If you *were* in fact using responsive design you would know for a fact that placement of content on the page is the responsibility of CSS, and not HTML. Have you never seen [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/)?

Comment: Thanks but this is just an instance where CSS is not an option. You're misreading the question. Believe me if I could use CSS here, it would be my first choice. PS Why do you say CSS is used to place content? I use it to style content. I use HTML for placement of content.

Comment: In this case I also don't agree with the conventional wisdom. I too have an edge case which I'm unable to reasonably solve with media queries alone. Tried it at length but there is no way. Yes I know the design is probably a bit weird (I said edge case) but I'm not in a position to just change that design. I need client side screen size detection and pass it to the server via AJAX.